# Best way to get query string from a URL in python?

Tags: python, django, comparison, urlencode, urlparse

I need to get the query string from this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?next=1&value=3 and I don't want to use [request.META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META). I have figured out that there are two more ways to get the query string:

1. **Using urlparse**
   urlparse.urlparse(url).query
2. **Using url encode**
   Use urlencode and pass the request.GET params dictionary into it to get the string representation.

So which way is better? My colleagues prefer urlencode but have not provided a satisfying explanation. They claim that urlparse calls urlencode internally which is something I'm not sure about since urlencode lives in the urllib module.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can make Query string using GET parameters like this

```
request.GET.urlencode()
```

This does not include the `?` prefix, and it may not return the keys in the same order as in the original request.

Comment: It's important to note that since QueryDict wraps an unordered dictionary, request.GET.urlencode() may not return keys in the same order that they appear in the original request URI.

Comment: That's a fundamental of dictionaries actually. Additionally, most query strings should be considered unordered if they are keyed. If it is a true list it will be ordered.

Answer (score 64):

Third option:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = 'http://something.com?blah=1&x=2'
>>> urlparse(url).query
'blah=1&x=2'
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
{'blah': ['1'], 'x': ['2']}
```

In Python 3+ this is available as:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
```

[Documentation for urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: Okay, not quite sure why you'd want the query string and not have it processed, but using urlparse is the most readable and understandable way.

Comment: This really helped me - I needed a Map (or some object) that held the params from a request URL!

Answer (score 59):

I prefer using

```
request.META['QUERY_STRING']
```

From docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

This does not include the `?` prefix.