# python extract id value from href source

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I've managed to extract the href URI's using beautifulsoup from the source of the page, however I now want to extract the UID value from multiple instances of the example below:

e.g

```
<a href="test.html?uid=5444974">
<a href="test.html?uid=5444972">
<a href="test.html?uid=54444972">
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you can extract the `href` attribute, then [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) will help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11281019/594589 as @DanLecocq suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> html
'<a href="test.html?uid=5444974">\n<a href="test.html?uid=5444972">\n<a href="test.html?uid=54444972">'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> ass = soup.find_all('a')
>>> r = re.compile('uid=(\d+)')
>>> uids = []
>>> for a in ass:
...     uids.append(r.search(a['href']).group(1))
... 
>>> uids
['5444974', '5444972', '54444972']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `urlparse` and `parse_qs`:

```
html = """<a href="test.html?uid=5444974">
<a href="test.html?uid=5444972">
<a href="test.html?uid=54444972">
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
soup = BS(html)
for a in soup('a', href=True):
    print parse_qs(urlparse(a['href']).query)['uid'][0]
```

Output:

```
5444974
5444972
54444972
```