# Django: Passing multiple keys into AJAX including a JavaScript seralised form and parsing them in python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

**What I need**

I'm trying to find a way to send a multi layered dictionary via AJAX to my server, including a JavaScript seralised form with the use of `serialize()`.

**The issue**

When I use `data: frm.serialize();`. It's a single layered json and it is easily parsed when returned to server with result:

```py
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['6aTZ7xey90sczae15069ZlbIiE7gVWW69RyeJBptUxadbgnBo8t8R0Nskg8S8Jzb', '6aTZ7xey90sczae15069ZlbIiE7gVWW69RyeJBptUxadbgnBo8t8R0Nskg8S8Jzb'], 'days': ['Mon', 'Wed'], 'no_weeks': ['1']}>
```

Then when using a nested dictionary with

````js
data: {'form':frm.serialize(),'additional_data':12,'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()}```
````

I get:

```py
<QueryDict: {'form': ['csrfmiddlewaretoken=IF2D4vTBjaQSsrE4oY3Lb36jekPB5nZbLmHSGz4w4HyT4xNEH6qK3II3gWQdiaCg&days=Mon&days=Thu&no_weeks=2&csrfmiddlewaretoken=IF2D4vTBjaQSsrE4oY3Lb36jekPB5nZbLmHSGz4w4HyT4xNEH6qK3II3gWQdiaCg'], 'additional_data': ['12'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['IF2D4vTBjaQSsrE4oY3Lb36jekPB5nZbLmHSGz4w4HyT4xNEH6qK3II3gWQdiaCg']}>
```

**What i've tried**

I have attempted with use of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11281019/11475846) to use `urllib` to parse the form section of the data into a separate variable. Like so:

```py
x = parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(request.POST['form']).query)
```

This returns an empty dicitonary.

**Code**

***HTML***

```html
<form method="post" id="replicate_form"> 
   [..more code]
</form>
```

***Javscript***

```js
function send_replication_data() {
    var frm = $('#replicate_form')
    var form_server_response = submit_formdata(frm)
}

// parent function to handle replcation form saving

$('#create_replicate_booking_button').on('click', function() {
    send_replication_data() 
});

// submit booking data ajax

function submit_formdata(frm) {
    var tmp = $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            async:false,
            url: window.location.href,
            data: {'form':frm.serialize(),
                   'additional_data':12,
                   'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()}

        });
    return tmp.responseJSON;
}
```

Possibly I could somehow make use of whatever Django is doing in it's middleware to a parse the form data in the first scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard **URL-encoded** notation.

You could use `urllib.parse.parse_qs` to parse a query string(form data sent to server by GET) or `request.POST['form']` since it uses the same encoding.

Query strings are element of **urls**, while `request.POST['form']` has no attribute called `query`

```
from urllib import parse
x = parse.parse_qs(request.POST['form']).query)
```